# keyboard sporadically stops working on one (otherwise functional) usb port, but not the other

Tags: usb, keyboard

I have an Apple keyboard that recently stopped working when plugged into its normal USB port. However, it works fine when plugged into a second USB port on my laptop. The first USB port still works with other devices, like my mouse. However the keyboard occasionally starts working again when unplugged and replugged into the first port. What is going on?

dmesg log when keyboard doesn’t work:

```
[ 7198.061251] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[ 7198.210261] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=1006
[ 7198.210266] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7198.210270] usb 1-1: Product: Keyboard Hub
[ 7198.210272] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Apple, Inc.
[ 7198.210275] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[ 7198.210966] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[ 7198.211002] hub 1-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
[ 7198.215986] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 15
```

dmesg log when keyboard *does* work (same USB port)

```
[ 7463.912999] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[ 7464.061992] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=1006
[ 7464.061997] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7464.062000] usb 1-1: Product: Keyboard Hub
[ 7464.062003] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Apple, Inc.
[ 7464.062006] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[ 7464.062659] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[ 7464.062705] hub 1-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
[ 7464.349064] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[ 7464.456083] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=024f
[ 7464.456087] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 7464.456091] usb 1-1.2: Product: Apple Keyboard
[ 7464.456093] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[ 7464.460757] input: Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:05AC:024F.0005/input/input40
[ 7464.517834] apple 0003:05AC:024F.0005: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2/input0
[ 7464.520509] input: Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/0003:05AC:024F.0006/input/input41
[ 7464.577574] apple 0003:05AC:024F.0006: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2/input1
```

Sometimes 6-7 “keyboard hubs” get detected and logged, even though I only plugged in one keyboard.

I think the keyboard sometimes disconnects itself right after plugging it in, how do I fix this?

OS: ubuntu 17.10

laptop: Dell Precision 5520

Comment: Does it work all the time with a different OS such as Windows of MacOS?

Comment: @user68186 , can’t tell, i don’t have a windows machine, and my osx laptop is the new macbook which doesn’t have USB ports

Comment: @user68186 i should also add I had a similar issue on a different laptop (also with ubuntu 17.10 installed), but instead, the ports in question were one of the hub ports on a monitor, and the first port (which is no longer consistently working now). The keyboard (same keyboard) would sporadically stop working when plugged into the monitor port, but work fine and reliably when plugged into the now-problematic laptop port.

Comment: Do you suspect one USB port is becoming faulty whilst the other USB port is working perfectly?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix i doubt it, it’s happened on both a new and old laptop, and the ports in question seem to migrate depending on how many hubs are plugged in.

Comment: @taylorswift Thanks for clearing that up... I wasn't so... swift.

Comment: "...depending on how many hubs are plugged in." This may be the cause. Once I had one hub connected to another hub  in a monitor and the keyboard connected to the second hub which was connected to the monitor's USB port. It worked fine until reboot. After reboot the keyboard was dead until I unplugged the hub from the monitor's one USB port and plugged it into the second USB port in the monitor. Then the keyboard worked until the next reboot. Then I had to switch the hub from second to the first. So I figured the solution was to remove the second hub.